# Copying rows from one into another table in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two databases - db1 and db2 as follows:

**db1..Model**

```
ModelId ModelName
0       BMW
```

**db1..Category**

```
CategoryId  CategoryName
0           Undercarriage
1           Engine
```

**db1..ItemList**

```
ModelId CategoryId      DataId  Name
0       0               1       cap
0       0               2       cushion
0       0               3       spacer
0       1               1       cushion
```

Then I copied Model and Category from db1 into db2:

**db2..Model**

```
Id  ModelName
1   BMW
```

**db2..Category**

```
Id  CategoryName
1   Undercarriage
2   Engine
```

How can I write the records into **db2..Item** in order the rows shoul be like this:

```
Id  ModelId     CategoryId  DataId  Name
1   1           1           1       cap
2   1           1           2       cushion
3   1           1           3       spacer
4   1           2           1       cushion
```

Comment: Are ModelName and CategoryName unique within their respective tables?

Comment: ModelName is unique, CategoryName is no unique in db1..Category, so I copied only distinct values for CategoryName into db2..Category, therefore now CategoryName is also unique in db2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that db1 and db2 are on the same server, something like this should work:

```
INSERT INTO db2.dbo.Item (ModelId, CategoryId, DataId, Name)
SELECT
    (
        SELECT Model.Id
        FROM db2.dbo.Model
        WHERE db2.dbo.Model.ModelName = (
            SELECT Model.ModelName
            FROM db1.dbo.Model
            WHERE Model.ModelId = ItemList.ModelId
        )
    )
    (
        SELECT Category.Id
        FROM db2.dbo.Category
        WHERE db2.dbo.Category.CategoryName = (
            SELECT Category.CategoryName
            FROM db1.dbo.Category
            WHERE Category.CategoryId = ItemList.CategoryId
        )
    )
    DataId,
    Name
FROM db1.dbo.ItemList
```

Comment: Jon, thanks a lot! It's working - I just changed a little one statement 'WHERE (Category.CategoryId = ItemList.CategoryId' AND Category.ModelId = ItemList.ModelId). Otherwise, I got an error: "Subquery returned more than 1 value."